# Are there more rational or irrational numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

On the number line, are there more rational numbers or irrational numbers? I was told that there are equally many rational and irrational numbers. Is this correct? How could we prove that?

Comment: No, the person who told you that is wrong. There are more irrational numbers than rational numbers. Indeed, there are [uncountably](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set) many irrational numbers but only [countably](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set) many rational numbers.

Comment: As far as rational numbers and irrational numbers alternating is concerned, there is the fact that between any two rational numbers you can find an irrational number, and vice versa.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** The cardinality of the rational numbers, $|\Bbb Q|)$, is countable, but the cardinality of the real numbers, $|\Bbb R|$, is uncountable. How many irrational numbers $|\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q|$ must there be?

Comment: and in range [0,1[?

Comment: @Yukulélé You can make the same argument for [0,1]. And [0,1[ just has one less element.