# Which one is fewer?

Tags: irrational-numbers

i want to prove:
from 0 to 1 number of Rational numbers are fewer than Irrational numbers.
How does i prove that?
(Thanks and sorry for my awful English :D)

Comment: Look up Cantor diagonal argument

Comment: Duplicates: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/787650/328173), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/732/328173), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/474415/328173), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/10333/328173).

Comment: i want to solve it with integration.i saw a function that his value in rational numbers is 1 and in irrational is 0 .

Comment: if we integrate this function from 0 to 1 that gives us a number.

Comment: if our number near 0 we find out the number of irrational number is more than rational.

Comment: @SeyedMoeinAyyoubzadeh I suggest that you should edit your question to indicate that you hope to prove this using the integration of the function mentioned. (Not everyone approves of clarifying a question in the comments.  It is better to edit the question.)

Comment: What you need is Lebesgue Integration.